# Time-travelling demonslayers?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, demons

A friend mentioned a film they'd seen a few years ago about people who travelled through time to fight demons (live action, in English, probably since the mid-2000s). Does anyone recognise this description? She thought Shia LaBeouf was in it (which would suggest it was in the last ten years), but I can't spot anything matching the description in his filmography.

Comment: Is this v2.0 of [Time-traveling Robots meme](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5133/54887)?

Comment: the demons killed the robots, obviously.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Unless I am a pawn in an extremely convoluted scheme with no actual benefit to anyone, which is always possible.

Comment: Not [Army of Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_Darkness), I assume? Also, if there's any chance it's a TV show rather than a film, there was some time-traveling demon hunting in [Friday the 13th: The Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th:_The_Series), the [young male lead looked a bit like Shia LaBeouf](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-uRuoicaNt0k/T_jiw6SiF9I/AAAAAAAAAZg/EUP9BGQNdMw/s1600/images.jpg).

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a longshot, but could it possibly be [Constantine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0360486/?ref_=nv_sr_2)? It came out in 2005, stars Keanu Reeves with Shia LaBeouf as his plucky sidekick, and they spend a fair bit of time fighting demons.

The time travel thing doesn't quite happen, but there are a few scenes of "Hell" which looks like a post-apocalyptic LA. Lots of broken buildings and rubble everywhere, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I won't get chance to check this with the friend who was describing it until Monday, but I haven't forgotten! I had ruled out Constantine due to the lack of time travel, but should check this with her.